# Erratic mouse behavior in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and have noticed lots of erratic behavior on the part of the mouse pointer. It sometimes makes rapid jumps, not traveling at a consistent speed, making it very difficult to target various objects on the screen. Sometimes the mouse pointer just disappears for periods of time, and very often the mouse pointer flickers off and on. For example, as I am typing now, each time I begin typing the mouse pointer starts flickering, and when I stop typing the flickering stops (even when the mouse is positioned away from the window I am typing in). Sometimes the mouse pointer disappears when inside of a certain window, but then re-appears outside of that window. The only word I can use to describe the problem is "erratic" behavior. It is really a consitent problem, every time I boot up, all the time.
Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps yoou could edit your post to indicate the hardware base and whether you are using USB or PS2

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not an explanation, but I have had the same issue with a wireless microsoft mouse.

It moved erratically and the movement speed was way off compared to the settings.

The solution was to *remove* the mouse from USB and plug it in again. This made it behave normal again.